# Ubuntu 22.04LTS, bluetooth dongle not working D-Bus connection failure

Tags: drivers, usb, 22.04, bluetooth, dbus

I wanted to connect my bluetooth headset to my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system.
I purchased a Edimax usb bluetooth dongle (BT8500 with rtl8761b chipset) which has a ubuntu driver for a supported kernel version of 2.6.32 – 5.3.

So far so good.
Downloaded driver followed instructions to create the files in the /lib/firmware/ directory.
Rebooted and run **hciconfig -a**

Bluetooth appeared in settings but could not connect to anything....Digging deeper  to  trouble shooting I found that the bluetoothd could not get on D-Bus. And
**/usr/bin/snap run bluez**

D-Bus setup failed: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: Permission denied

some extracts from the system (if there are other commands happy to get)

```
neale@Edward:~$ **hciconfig -a**
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
BD Address: 08:BE:AC:2F:A7:C7  ACL MTU: 1021:6  SCO MTU: 255:12
UP RUNNING 
RX bytes:810 acl:0 sco:0 events:64 errors:0
TX bytes:5338 acl:0 sco:0 commands:64 errors:0
Features: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xfd 0x7b 0x87
Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT 
Name: 'Edward'
Class: 0x7c0104
Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer, Audio, Telephony
Device Class: Computer, Desktop workstation
HCI Version: 5.1 (0xa)  Revision: 0x9a9
LMP Version: 5.1 (0xa)  Subversion: 0x8a6b
Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (93)


**systemctl status snap.bluez.bluez.service**
× snap.bluez.bluez.service - Service for snap application bluez.bluez
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap.bluez.bluez.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-02-08 19:28:26 NZDT; 20min ago
   Main PID: 1541 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 32ms

Feb 08 19:28:26 Edward systemd[1]: snap.bluez.bluez.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 08 19:28:26 Edward bluetoothd[1541]: Unable to get on D-Bus
Feb 08 19:28:26 Edward systemd[1]: snap.bluez.bluez.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Feb 08 19:28:26 Edward systemd[1]: Stopped Service for snap application bluez.bluez.
Feb 08 19:28:26 Edward systemd[1]: snap.bluez.bluez.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 08 19:28:26 Edward systemd[1]: snap.bluez.bluez.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 08 19:28:26 Edward systemd[1]: Failed to start Service for snap application bluez.bluez.
neale@Edward:~$ 

neale@Edward:~$ **sudo /usr/bin/snap run bluez**
D-Bus setup failed: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: Permission denied


neale@Edward:~$ **ls -la /var/run/dbus/**
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  60 Feb  7 22:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 37 root root 960 Feb  8 16:29 ..
srw-rw-rw-  1 root root   0 Feb  7 22:06 system_bus_socket


neale@Edward:~$ ps ax|grep dbus
   1020 ?        Ss     0:10 @dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
   2207 ?        Ss     0:01 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
   2428 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 11 --address=unix:path=/run/user/1000/at-spi/bus
  11785 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
  11786 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
  85726 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto dbus




lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [8086:1502] (rev 06)
DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [1458:e000]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1d2d] (rev 06)
--
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:6621]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] [10de:13c2] (rev a1)
--
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82575EB Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10a7] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82575EB Gigabit Network Connection [8086:0000]
Kernel driver in use: igb
Kernel modules: igb
06:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82575EB Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10a7] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82575EB Gigabit Network Connection [8086:0000]
Kernel driver in use: igb
Kernel modules: igb
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168]   (rev 06)

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1b1c:0c04 Corsair Link Cooling Node
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 7392:c611 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd Edimax    Bluetooth Adapter
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 2109:0811 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c016 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 125f:a83a A-DATA Technology Co., Ltd. HD330
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
```

2023-02-15 Update
Removed bluez completely

```
`● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-02-15 18:35:44 NZDT; 1 day 2h ago
   Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1034 (bluetoothd)
 Status: "Running"
  Tasks: 1 (limit: 38335)
 Memory: 2.2M
    CPU: 211ms
 CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
         └─1034 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Feb 16 20:33:23 Edward bluetoothd[1034]: Failed to set mode: Not Supported (0x0c)
Feb 16 20:33:23 Edward bluetoothd[1034]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 16 20:33:23 Edward bluetoothd[1034]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 16 20:33:23 Edward bluetoothd[1034]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Feb 16 20:33:23 Edward bluetoothd[1034]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Feb 16 20:33:23 Edward bluetoothd[1034]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Feb 16 20:33:23 Edward bluetoothd[1034]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Feb 16 20:33:23 Edward bluetoothd[1034]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Feb 16 20:33:23 Edward bluetoothd[1034]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
Feb 16 20:33:23 Edward bluetoothd[1034]: src/adv_monitor.c:btd_adv_monitor_power_down() Unexpected NULL   btd_adv_monitor_manager object upon power down`
```

not sure why the code wraps around it looked ok in the preview window .

Comment: What result from terminal for `lsusb`  For some reason the class is not correct in the hciconfig results

Comment: You might want to remove the bluez snap if you installed it

Comment: Thank you for the feedback ... Really out of my depth here.   Removed bluez,  still have challenge Not supported mode 0x0c

Comment: Driver for kernels 2.6.32 – 5.3 is unlikely to work with Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Your bug report shows an unsupported module named rtk_btusb that is not needed

Answer (score 0):

This device `7392:c611 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd Edimax    Bluetooth Adapter` is not currently supported by the installed kernel (5.15), neither it is supported by the next 5.19 Ubuntu kernel.

Support for this device has been added by [this patch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?h=v6.1.12&id=c7577014b74c5369490715015db096182f1a2a23) to Linux mainline.

If you install a recent mainline kernel, the device should work.

Also it is possible to build a dkms driver for Ubuntu kernels too.

It makes sense to report a bug to Launchpad by running `ubuntu-bug linux` asking to backport that patch.

Comment: The patch is not needed, mine works fine with 5.15 in 22.04 and with 5.19 in 22.10.  I think this is a case of operator error

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback in that the device is currently not supported :(. I have lodged a Ubuntu-bug request (fingers crossed in the future). Not confident to follow the instructions provided by this patch above. Many thanks for the feed back.